# Android disconnects from Wi-Fi if I don't login to hot-spot. But there is no login needed

Tags: wi-fi, stock-android, wifi-hotspot, lan

Today I connected to a Wi-Fi network with two options:

1. Free access to **intranet**. No login required.
2. Paid access to full internet access. Login and payment required.

I just wanted to use the free service. But Android detected the connection as a hot-spot (login required),after about a minute it would disconnect from the hot spot, saying login timed out.

Really a bummer. The guy with iPad next to me wasn't having any issues.

Why does Android say it's a hot-spot and demand login when it's not necessary? How can I stop Android from disconnecting?

Samsung Galaxy S4, Android 4.3.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you're actually trying to connect to this internal **intranet** and not the internet? If not, then your description kind of answers your own question. The free service is not an internet connection but an internal interface for the host server. I don't think this is a device issue.

Comment: Correct. I wanted to connect only to the intranet. And I did. But then Android disconnected from the Wi-Fi because I didn't sign in.   Eventually I found a way round by setting up the connection with a proxy that doesn't actually do anything, but the connection holds. Thanks.